# Why do some webforms have their elements value in translation UI (/admin/config/regional/translate)?

Tags: 8, webforms, i18n-l10n

I have enabled [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module on a Drupal 8 installation.

For some reason, there are default webform templates such as "Donation" and "Contact Us" which have their `elements` values translated in the translation UI at **/admin/config/regional/translate**. The problem is that some webforms templates have HTML markup in their `elements` value like the following:

```
    '#prefix': '<div class="container-inline">'
    '#suffix': '</div>'
```

This will prevent saving any value, drupal telling the user that there are translations with invalid HTML tags:

> The submitted string contains disallowed HTML: *information: '#title': 'Your Information' '#type': fieldset first_name: '#title': 'First Name' '#type': textfield '#required': true last_name*
>
> etc...

Regarding this issue, I have a few questions:

1. what actions trigger the `elements` value availability in this interface? On install, on config save...?
2. do the **webform** module really uses this interface to translate the content of the forms?
3. and if yes, am I missing a module or something to make it work?
4. and if not, should this be considered as a bug? The closest issue I have found is this one: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2913548

It looks like this is this template: https://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform/tree/modules/webform_templates/config/install/webform.webform.template_job_application.yml?id=a988217057ed5ba842a3722de01f2d07df59e5e1

Comment: I have created an issue on Drupal.org issue tracker of the webform module: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2965060

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this was a side effect of the "translatability" of the elements value. A patch has been created by jrockowitz on the drupal issue tracker which will prevent having those values editable in the translation UI: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2965060#comment-12587556